# MS Access SQL: Creating a Query with Multiple Where Conditions

Tags: sql, ms-access

### Context

I have a stored Query in **MS Access 2016** that selects certain records from many different tables by relational id's and creates one table that is useful and readable. I have a 'Flags' table that contains 3 entries:

- (1, SourceA)
- (2, SourceB)
- (3, Both)

I want to create a **WHERE** clause to limit the results of the query to only records where TableA.Flag is equal to TableB.Flag or TableA has a flag of BOTH and TableB has a flag of SourceA.

In other SQL languages, this could be accomplished easily by grouping the where condition logic like so:

**WHERE** TableA.Flag = TableB.Flag **OR** (TableA.Flag = 3 **AND** TableB.Flag = 1)

MS Access, however, does not consider this valid logic, and adding extra nested parantheses (the usual workaround in MS Access SQL) has not produced a valid syntax either.

### Question

What is the proper syntax needed to functionally create the equivalent query in MS Access SQL?

Here are some examples that also did not work:

**WHERE** (TableA.Flag = TableB.Flag) **OR** ((TableA.Flag = 3) **AND** (TableB.Flag = 1))

**WHERE** ((TableA.Flag = TableB.Flag) **OR** ((TableA.Flag = 3) **AND** (TableB.Flag = 1)))

Here is the full query (which produces a syntax error message in the where clause line when I go to save it, and does not produce the same error message when the where clause line is removed):

```
SELECT TableB.ID AS ID
  , TableA.Name AS aliasA
  , TableC.Name AS aliasC
  , TableD.Name AS aliasD
  , TableE.Name AS aliasE
  , TableF.path AS aliasF1
  , TableF.path2 AS aliasF2
  , TableG.Property AS aliasG
  , TableH.Name AS aliasH
  , TableA.Flag AS Flag
FROM (((((( TableB 
  LEFT JOIN [TableA] ON TableB.aliasA = TableA.ID) 
  LEFT JOIN TableC ON TableB.PropertyC = TableC.ID)
  LEFT JOIN TableD ON TableB.PropertyD = TableD.ID) 
  LEFT JOIN TableE ON TableB.PropertyE = TableE.ID) 
  LEFT JOIN TableF ON TableB.PropertyF = TableF.ID) 
  LEFT JOIN TableG ON TableB.PropertyG = TableG.ID) 
  LEFT JOIN TableH ON TableB.PropertyH = TableH.ID
WHERE TableA.Flag = TableB.Flag OR (TableA.Flag = 3 AND TableB.Flag = 1)
ORDER BY TableB.ID;
```

**NOTE:** All of the parantheses used in the **FROM** clause in the above statement are ***absolutely necessary*** in MS Access SQL, even though they are ridiculously overused and laughably unnecessary in most other SQL languages.

**UPDATE: Simplified Query**

```
SELECT [TableB].[ID]
  , [TableA].[Name]
  , [TableA].[Flag]
FROM [TableB]
  LEFT JOIN [TableA] ON [TableB].[PropertyA] = [TableA].[ID]
WHERE [TableA].[Flag] = [TableB].[Flag] 
  OR ([TableA].[Flag] = 3 AND [TableB].[Flag] = 1)
ORDER BY [TableB].[ID];
```

Comment: what you mean access doesn't consider this valid logic? what is the problem? Tell us what is the error message, show us some sample data and expected output.

Comment: The where statements above are considered 'invalid syntax' by MS Access. An attempt to execute/save a query with those where clauses causes MS Access to throw an error message.

Comment: Show us the complete query.

Comment: Post your *real* WHERE clause - maybe you have a reserved word or illegal character... or...  Is the EXACT message: The Expression you entered contains invalid syntax.?

Comment: I have already isolated the problem to the 'Where' clause definitively, as when I remove the where clause, it works, and with it, it doesn't. But I will edit the question to include the query.

Comment: Exact message: Syntax error in query expression 'TableA.Flag = TableB.Flag OR (TableA.Flag = 3 AND TableB.Flag = 1)'.

Comment: Also your join on `Properties` does not seem to make sense as you never specify a column to join on.

Comment: This may help you. When I run into a problem like this with Access SQL, I create it in the query designer then go to SQL view and copy the query into my sub. My guess is that Access wants square brackets around something. That has burned me in the past.

Comment: Properties should be TableG. Sorry about that. And I appreciate the advice, Tony, but I actually did try adding square brackets before and that didn't solve it. I have also been burned by lack of square brackets before.

Comment: You should simplify the problem to just TableA and TableB first. What about just use the left side condition first  `WHERE TableA.Flag = TableB.Flag` does work? What about dont use the alias on the `SELECT TableA.Flag Flag` ??

Comment: Simplifying the code is a good suggestion. I'll edit the post to remove all queried columns except TableA and TableB. The alias are not causing the problem, as they are not used in the query itself, but we can remove them to further simplify.

Comment: I stand corrected about the `(((` syntax. What about moving the where into the join in the corresponding parenthesis? `... FROM ((((((TableB LEFT JOIN [TableA] ON TableB.aliasA = TableA.ID WHERE TableA.Flag = TableB.Flag OR (TableA.Flag = 3 AND TableB.Flag = 1)) LEFT JOIN...`

Comment: Have you tried taking out the 'where' clause, using the query designer and then run that query. I assume that should work. Then use the query designer to add part of the 'where' clause back in and test again. If all is still good, add the final part of the 'where' and run again. if that runs, have a beverage of choice; if it fails, remove the where and start over with the 'other' part first.

Comment: Can we assume you receive the same error on the simplified query?

Comment: No, actually, that's how I found out that Tony had provided the correct answer. The simplified query did not produce an error with/without square brackets. Adding the square brackets to the original query (where TableA was really called 'Parameters') solved the problem.

Comment: Excuse me if you think this is rude, but posting anything other than the actual code you use leads to a waste of time for all involved!! Myself, and many others, would have quickly noticed the use of a reserved word -- and saved everyone time!!

Comment: No, that's a fair critique, not rude. I'm sorry for wasting everyone's time. I was attempting to keep the content of the database (and it's subject matter) private. I would like to thank you for your helpful comments.

Answer (score 0):

The actual name of TableA was a reserved word (*Parameters*). Adding square brackets around the name of TableA worked perfectly. As it turns out, the following code IS valid syntax if TableA and TableB are not reserved keywords.

```
WHERE TableA.Flag = TableB.Flag OR (TableA.Flag = 3 AND TableB.Flag = 1)
```

Otherwise, the code should be:

```
WHERE [Parameters].[Flag] = [TableB].[Flag] OR ([Parameters].[Flag] = 3 AND [TableB].[Flag] = 1)
```

Props be to 'Tony' who provided the correct answer in the comments above.

Comment: Well the problem is you didn't say in your question `TableA` was a dummy. **facepalm**. Remember when we ask post the ***Real Query*** ?

Comment: Yes, that was definitely the problem. I should have said above that TableA was a dummy name. Thank you for your help.